# Saving ArrayList<Custom Object> in Fragment onPause Method

Tags: android, arraylist, onpause

I am trying to save an ArrayList with custom objects so that when i move to another fragment and come back to it, it doesnt have to reload the data. So far, i havent been able to achieve this despite making the object Parcelable and saving it in the onSaveInstanceState method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also hold a reference to this list in your ApplicationContext and get the data this way - so you do not need to serialize/deserialize

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use parcelable objects, you can try this:

```
1- By using GSON library, create jsonString from your Custom Arraylist.
2- Send this jsonString to Fragment by using Bundle.
3- Recieve jsonString from bundle and parse it to Custom Arraylist by using GSON Library again.
4- You can also save it to SharedPreferences as a String.
```

Note: This is not a good method but easy option for you.